# Dictionary In Django Model

Tags: django, django-models

I'm struggling with how to structure my models to allow me to capture some raw information that, once the instance is saved, I will no longer care about programmatically but will still want to save for posterity.

Specifically, I need to capture a variety of data-points tied to specific days of the week, but really those are only useful in calculating the information I do care about (such as total hours, overtime, etc). While I could do this all in the Form/View I do want to save the raw data as I'll want to display it later (but wont need it for calculating anything).

I could create a Day model and use a many-to-one relationship, but I'd like to not have to query the db 7+ times every time I display or process a timesheet.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

```
class Timesheet(models.Model):
     #Begin Stuff I Care About
     employee = models.CharField()
     company = models.CharField()
     week_ending = models.DateField()

     total_hours = models.DecimalField()
     regular_hours = models.DecimalField()
     overtime_hours = models.DecimalField()
     doubletime_hours = models.DecimalField()
     #End stuff I care about

     #For Each Day of Week - Stuff I Will Not Care About
     time_in_monday = models.TimeField()
     lunch_out_monday = models.TimeField()
     lunch_in_monday = models.TimeField()
     time_out_monday = models.TimeField()
     total_monday = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2)

     time_in_tuesday = models.TimeField()
     lunch_out_tuesday = models.TimeField()
     lunch_in_tuesday = models.TimeField()
     time_out_tuesday = models.TimeField()
     total_tuesday = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2)

     ... #You get the idea
```

Comment: Is the timesheet only written once, at the end of the week? or is it written incrementally as the days move on?

Comment: Ideally users would have access to the timesheet everyday to enter their hours and could bulk enter their hours at the end of the week.

Comment: you could store the day data in a JSON string in a textfield and just dumps/load it when you need to modify it?

Comment: or a json field for each day if you're afraid of capacity issues?

Comment: something like:
`monday_data = models.TextField()
tuesday_data = models.TextField()`...etc

Comment: actually, thinking about it, I think the David542's suggestion is probably the best.  Categorizing data by day of the week isn't necessarily a good thing, because you're binding that data to a certain time zone.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest structuring your database in a more normalized fashion so that you can more easily query it and the table won't be so unwieldy. An example might be:

```
class Timesheet(models.Model):
    employee = models.CharField()
    company = models.CharField()
    time_in = models.DateTimeField()
    time_out = models.DateTimeField()
```

From this, you can save a point of data every time an employee checks in or checks out. You can also calculate their hours, etc. I suppose you may also want to save additional fields to suit your purposes, but the above should give you a good starting point.

If you wanted to get a query for John on Monday, you would use the `WEEKDAY()` function, for example:

```
SELECT time_in, time_out FROM Timesheet WHERE employee = "John" AND WEEKDAY(time_in) = 0
```

If your employees are from all over the world, you might want to store a `tz_offset` column in the database and keep all dates in UTC. If all the employees are working in the same timezone, then it's simpler and you can just store the time in the local timezone.

Comment: the only issue here is the queries to get the data for each day...they'll get pretty complex.

Comment: although...this might be the better solution.  What exactly is "monday" and "tuesday"...it's a time period that is dependent upon your timezone.